# Select lines beginning with a pattern within a preselected text between two different patterns

Tags: sed, macos

I have this UNIX script in two steps that does what I need, i.e. that prints the selected lines beginning with a pattern (x followed by digits) within a preselected text between two different patterns (PAT1 and PAT2):

1) Preselected text between two different patterns (PAT1 and PAT2), excluding the lines with PAT1 and PAT2 - [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT1/!{/PAT2/!p;};}'  file.txt > newfile.txt
```

2) Print the selected lines beginning with a pattern (x followed by digits) within a preselected text

```
sed -n '/^x [[:digit:]]*/p'  newfile.txt > newfile2.txt
```

Is there a way to get the same result in one step?

I have tried this script, but it does not work (the code stays blocked):

```
sed -e '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT1/!{/PAT2/!p;};}' ; '/^x [[:digit:]]*/p'  file.txt > newfile.txt
```

I am working on OSX, not Linux.

Comment: You have to pipe to, not just "append" a second sed script after the `;`. something like `sed -e '...' file.txt | sed -e '...' > newfile.txt`. The first sed gets the input file, second redirects to output file. And in between you have a PIPE instead of a temp file. (I don't fully understand what the seds are doing)

Comment: A sample input were helpful...

Comment: @rastafile If I do that it basically copy the content of file.txt in newfile.txt.

Comment: Oh yes I see -- you went from `-n` to `-e` switch in your one-step variant. The 'quiet' option -n is important. Sorry, I focused only on the piping  ;) I agree with guest's answer, esp. about the `;` in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight adjustment to the first `sed` operation should do it:

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/^x [[:digit:]]*/p;}' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

- There's probably no need to try excluding `PAT1` & `PAT2`, unless they occur in the same line as `^x [0-9]` If this is the case:

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT1\|PAT2/!{/^x [0-9]*/p;};}' file.txt
```

will also exclude `PAT1` & `PAT2`

---

The reason why the following doesn't appear to do anything:

```
sed -e '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT1/!{/PAT2/!p;};}' ; '/^x [[:digit:]]*/p'
                                            ^
```

is that the first command (`sed`) did not recieve any input from a file, so is waiting for input from `standard input` i.e. your keyboard.

The semicolon is unquoted and forms part of the shell's syntax for interpreting the commands you gave it. In simple terms, the above line means: `execute a command named 'sed', then execute a command named '/^x [[:digit:]]*/p'` – which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, the following script worked: 
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/^x [[:digit:]]*/p;}'  file.txt > newfile.txt
 , i.e. without --.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the `--` from the answer